# apply an aspect to other assembly class methods calls

Tags: c#, postsharp

I've created a simple aspect:

```
[Serializable()]
public class NullableCallAspect : PostSharp.Aspects.OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(PostSharp.Aspects.MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Instance == null)
            args.FlowBehavior = PostSharp.Aspects.FlowBehavior.Return;
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want that whichever `instance.method` call that `instance == null` it doesn't enter in the method. I'm figuring out, I need to change the inheritance of the aspect. So, I would need to change `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` by another one. This would be the first question.

The other question is around how to apply this aspect to methods calls from classes that inherits of an interface of another assembly.

I've tried this, but it doesn't quite work:

```
[assembly: UI.Aspects.NullableCallAspect(
    AttributeTargetAssemblies = "UIAppearanceExtensibility",
    AttributeTargetTypes = "UI.Appearance.Extensibility.*.I*AppearanceManager",
    AttributeTargetMembers = "handle*"
)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of aspects would require call site interception which is not supported by PostSharp. Both OnMethodBoundaryAspect and MethodInterceptionAspect modify target method not call site itself - instance is still required when calling method decorated by these aspects.

EDIT:
There is a hack how to force PostSharp to intercept call sites. It is when an aspect is multicasted to types in different assembly. If all methods are implemented in project **ClassLibrary1** and they are called just from **MyApplication** project then the aspect can be multicasted in **MyApplication** project like this:

```
[assembly:
    NullableCallAspect(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "ClassLibrary1", AttributeTargetTypes = "ClassLibrary1.*",
        AttributeTargetMembers = "handle*", AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method)]
```

If there is a convention that all implementation of **IAppearanceManager** end has name with suffix **AppearanceManager** then the multicast needs to be changed:

```
[assembly:
    NullableCallAspect(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "ClassLibrary1", AttributeTargetTypes = "ClassLibrary1.*AppearanceManager",
        AttributeTargetMembers = "handle*", AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method)]
```

If there is no such convention then a [IAspectProvider](http://doc.postsharp.net/iaspectprovider) can be used for the multicasting.

This is not usable when there are calls to methods decorated by **NullableCallAspect** within same assembly - call sites are not intercepted in such case.

Comment: Yes, every interface is defined on **ClassLibrary1** and every call to its methods are made from **MyApplication1**. As you can see [here](http://s16.photobucket.com/user/jeusdi/media/snip3.png.html), **MyApplication1** is `UI` and **ClassLibrary1** is `UIExtensibility`. However it doesn't work. I have no idea how to solve that.

Comment: It is not enough to have all interfaces in ClassLibrary1 to make the hack work. All interface implementations needs to be defined in ClassLibrary1 as well.

Comment: Ok. I wanted to avoid to check the `null.method` calls. I've created a dummy implementation for my types, where my IoC doesn't provide me any implementation. The dummy implementation is provided by an NSubstitute proxy. Thanks for all.